# How to set container width inside Expanded ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am unable to set width for the `Container` when I wrap `ListView` inside `Expanded` widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Center(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 30),
        child: Text(
          'Transactions History',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 25,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 30,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              width: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Card(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25, vertical: 15),
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: What would you expect this to look like?

Comment: I think your container won't be visible as it is. The width is actually 100 but without a height it won't be visible because it's doesn't seem to be drawing any visible child.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the `Container` of your listItem in the `itemBuilder`  inside an `Align` widget.

So your code in the `itemBuilder` will look like this:

```
return Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
  child: Container(
    width: 100,
    color: Colors.red,
    child: Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
           horizontal: 25,
           vertical: 15,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```